# Does sequelize-typescript memoize repositories when used with repository mode?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, repository, sequelize-typescript

I built a Node JS app with express, sequelize and sequelize-typescript (db is MySQL). I define my model with classes and decorators using sequelize-typescript. In my scenario I have to connect to multiple different databases that have the same model and for that reason I initialize multiple sequelize instances with their own db config in *repository mode*. I do queries in a similar way as shown in this snippet:

```js
import { ExampleModel } from 'models/example-model';
import { DbManager } from 'db-manager';

const connection = DbManager.getConnection(/*...*/);
const exampleRepository = connection.getRepository(ExampleModel);
const exampleData = await exampleRepository.findAll();
```

where `connection` is a Sequelize instance. It works as expected - I'm able to use the same model to do queries from different sequelize instances.

My question is - does Sequelize-Typescript memoize these repositories or I need to optimize things myself. In other words, does this code:

```js
const exampleRepository1 = connection.getRepository(ExampleModel);
const exampleRepository2 = connection.getRepository(ExampleModel);
```

create two individual repository objects in memory internally reuses the same?